# Find maximal subrectangles

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program in java and I have a (0,1) matrix. I want to calculate the number of maximal sub-rectangles of this 2D array consisting only of zeros.

sub-rectangle A is maximal if A is not a sub-rectangle of a bigger sub-rectangle B such that B only consists of zeros too.

How should I count such sub-rectangles?

I have this code to check if a sub-rectangle of size height*width beginning from (top,left) only have zeros or not but I do not know what to do with the maximal part:

```
static boolean areAllZeros(int[][] matrix, int top, int left, int height, int width) {
int maxHeight = matrix.length;
int maxWidth = matrix[0].length;
int bottom = top + height;
int right = left + width;
if (bottom > maxHeight || right > maxWidth)
    return false;
for (int i = top; i < bottom; ++i)
    for (int j = left; j < right; ++j)
        if (matrix[i][j] != 0)
            return false;
return true;
```

}

For example, the answer for the following matrix is 3:

0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

((1)the 2*2 rectangle starting from (0,0), (2)the 2*5 rectangle starting from (0,3) and (3)the 1*8 rectangle starting from (1,0))

Comment: @PradeepSimha sorry,I have edited my question.

Comment: Oh! it's my code.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem. I created algorithm which works this way:

- every zero is treated as trivial rectangle in the beginning
- every rectangle is made bigger in all directions

  - if it is not possible the rectangle is minimal and counted to result
  - if it is possible, repeat

All rectangles for which it is not yet decided are held in queue. The queue must have at least partial ordering (in example there is total ordering) which guarantee that larger rectangles are always processed after smaller rectangles.

It seems to me, however, the algorithm is not optimal. Perhaps the dynamic programming could be applied here.

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SO {

    record RectangleOfZeros(int t, int l, int h, int w) implements Comparable<RectangleOfZeros> {
        // Comparator must ensure expanded rectangle is always greater than the original. Hence only comparison by h then by w is necessary, the other comparisons are for optimization and stabililty in debugging.
        static final Comparator<RectangleOfZeros> NATURAL = Comparator 
                .comparingInt((RectangleOfZeros r) -> r.h + r.w)
                .thenComparingInt((RectangleOfZeros r) -> r.h)
                .thenComparingInt((RectangleOfZeros r) -> r.w)
                .thenComparingInt((RectangleOfZeros r) -> r.t)
                .thenComparingInt((RectangleOfZeros r) -> r.l);
        @Override
        public int compareTo(RectangleOfZeros that) {
            return NATURAL.compare(this,that);
        }
        // if for this rectangle there exists another row or column full of zeros in given direction, returns the bigger rectangle, otherwise returns null
        public RectangleOfZeros expandRight(int[][] matrix) {
            int W = matrix[0].length;
            int testedColumn = l + w;
            if (testedColumn >= W) return null; // beyond boundary
            for (int row = t; row < t + h; row++) if (matrix[row][testedColumn] == 1) return null;
            return new RectangleOfZeros(t, l, h, w + 1);
        }
        public RectangleOfZeros expandLeft(int[][] matrix) {
            int testedColumn = l - 1;
            if (testedColumn < 0) return null; // beyond boundary
            for (int row = t; row < t + h; row++) if (matrix[row][testedColumn] == 1) return null;
            return new RectangleOfZeros(t, l - 1, h, w + 1);
        }
        public RectangleOfZeros expandDown(int[][] matrix) {
            int H = matrix.length;
            int testedRow = t + h;
            if (testedRow >= H) return null; // beyond boundary
            for (int column = l; column < l + w; column++) if (matrix[testedRow][column] == 1) return null;
            return new RectangleOfZeros(t, l, h + 1, w);
        }
        public RectangleOfZeros expandUp(int[][] matrix) {
            int testedRow = t - 1;
            if (testedRow < 0) return null; // beyond boundary
            for (int column = l; column < l + w; column++) if (matrix[testedRow][column] == 1) return null;
            return new RectangleOfZeros(t - 1, l, h + 1, w);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String matrixInput1 = """
                00100000
                00000000""";
        String matrixInput2 = """
                010101010
                101010101
                010101010
                101010101""";
        String matrixInput3 = """
                0000001
                0000000
                0001000
                0000000
                0000000
                0001000""";
        String matrixInput4 = """
                0000001
                0000010
                0000100
                0001000
                0010000
                0100000
                1000000""";
        String matrixInput5 = """
                0000000
                0000000
                0000000
                0000000
                0000000""";
        String matrixInput6 = """
                1111
                1111
                1111""";
        int[][] matrix = Pattern.compile("\n").splitAsStream(matrixInput1).map(s -> s.chars().map(c -> c - '0').toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
        int H = matrix.length, W = matrix[0].length;
        SortedSet<RectangleOfZeros> queue = new TreeSet<>();
        SortedSet<RectangleOfZeros> result = new TreeSet<>();
        for (int t = 0; t < H; t++) for (int l = 0; l < W; l++) if (matrix[t][l] == 0) queue.add(new RectangleOfZeros(t, l, 1, 1)); // initial fill of atomic rectangles
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            RectangleOfZeros r = queue.first();
            queue.remove(r);
            boolean isMaximal = true;
            RectangleOfZeros expanded;
            if ((expanded = r.expandRight(matrix)) != null) {
                queue.add(expanded);
                isMaximal = false;
            }
            if ((expanded = r.expandLeft(matrix)) != null) {
                queue.add(expanded);
                isMaximal = false;
            }
            if ((expanded = r.expandDown(matrix)) != null) {
                queue.add(expanded);
                isMaximal = false;
            }
            if ((expanded = r.expandUp(matrix)) != null) {
                queue.add(expanded);
                isMaximal = false;
            }
            if (isMaximal) {
                result.add(r);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.size());
        //System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```